# How to store 4 lines of results, displayed on screen, from a while loop, into a table

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, insert

I have calculated the average price of products by type in a table and gotten the results into my screen. How do I store them into a table as well.  Here is the code I have. it works other than to store into a table.

```
function mostrarDatos ($resultado) {
    if ($resultado !=NULL) {
        echo "- Promedio de Categoria ".'Producto_Prioridad'." es:".$resultado['total_average']."<br/>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br/>No hay más datos!!! <br/>";
    }
}
$link = mysqli_connect("db", "user", "pass");
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
$promedio = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT AVG( Producto_Precio ) as total_average FROM`Natan_Productos` GROUP BY Producto_Prioridad");
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($promedio)){  // loops 4 times and displays on screen. How to store into table as well
    mostrarDatos($fila);
}
mysqli_free_result($promedio);
mysqli_close($link);
```

for results I get:

> - Promedio de Categoria Producto_Prioridad es:150.0000  //Loop 1
> - Promedio de Categoria Producto_Prioridad es:38.3333   //Loop 2
> - Promedio de Categoria Producto_Prioridad es:30.0000   //Loop 3
> - Promedio de Categoria Producto_Prioridad es:31.6667   //Loop 4

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I do have a table for the results. Its called Natan_Procesos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not familiar with php & mysql.

First, you should have a table for storing the result.Let's create a simple table if you do not have one.

```
create table result_for_total_average ( avg_info varchar(256) );
```

Then, modify your function like this.

```
function mostrarDatos ($resultado, $link) {
    if ($resultado !=NULL) {
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO result_for_total_average values("."- Promedio de Categoria ".'Producto_Prioridad'." es:".$resultado['total_average'].")");
    }else {
        echo "<br/>No hay más datos!!! <br/>";
    }
}
$link = mysqli_connect("db", "user", "pass");
mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
$promedio = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT AVG( Producto_Precio ) as total_average FROM`Natan_Productos` GROUP BY Producto_Prioridad");
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($promedio)){  // loops 4 times and displays on screen. How to store into table as well
   mostrarDatos($fila);
}
mysqli_free_result($promedio);
mysqli_close($link);
```

The table I created is just simple enough to store the result, you can create your own one. If you do not know how to, here is a good start:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp. 
If you want learn more about how php and mysql work together, you can reference to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: I get 2 errors with this code:  Warning: Missing argument 2 for mostrarDatos(), called in /home/.../connect7.php on line 22 and defined in /home/.../connect7.php on line 10                         line 10 is funcion mostrarDatos... and 22 is mostrarDatos (fila);

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/.../connect7.php on line 12    line 12 is mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Natan_...

Comment: Ok. I got it to work, I didnt need the text in with the avg value though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for inserting your new products

```
id (auto increment) | name | country | number
```

---

```
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($promedio))
{  
    $product = mostrarDatos($fila);
    // Mysql Insert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) statement, which looks something like so,

`INSERT INTO <table-x> (<column-x>) SELECT <column-y> FROM <table-y>;`

or in your case, something like so,

```
INSERT INTO Natan_Average_Productos (product)
SELECT CONCAT("- Promedio de Categoria Producto_Prioridad es:", AVG(Producto_Precio)) AS total_average
FROM Natan_Productos
GROUP BY Producto_Prioridad;
```